In LibreOfficeBase Forms, How to make one listbox affect what shows in another listbox if the tables for each listbox are related by a junction table?
I don't really know how to ask this question properly but this what I'm trying to do is that when I select a value from let say listBoxA, which would be getting its data from table A, the value selected would then be compared from a junction table and depending on the relations listbox B would then have only use values from table B that have a relationships with table A
Ex.
Table 1. Size Categories
| PK | SizeCategoryID |       0       |       1        |
|    | Size Category  | Tshirt Sizes  |  Memory Sizes  |

Table 2. Size Values
| PK | SizeValueID | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3  | 4  | 
|    | Size Value  | S | M | L | 32 | 64 |

Table 3. Size Relationships
| PK FK1 | SizeCategoryID | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 
| PK Fk2 | SizeValueID    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|        | SortOrder      | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

If
Size Categories
-> Tshirt Sizes
Memory Sizes
Then
Size Values
S
M
L
I tried to do this but I guess the effect instead was that only Size Values with relationships with ANY Size Category
Image:RelationshipQuery
I'm Kinda at a loss and I have no experience when it comes to using macros
This was the closest thing I found to what I wanted to do
libreoffice base create a list filtered by another list's value
But I struggle to modify the code to suit my database

It might be worth posting at ask.libreoffice.org to see if someone is willing to work on this. Otherwise, maybe it would help to explain further about "I struggle to modify the code to suit my database" — did you get the original solution to work, and if so, what modifications did you try that didn't work? If the question is about a specific problem then it will be easier to answer. Finally, once you get it working, you can post an answer to help others who may come across this question.
